# SQL retrieve error

Tags: sql

I want to retrieve all the details from bookings table if they are in the range of guest check in and check out dates. Guest selected check in date is ‘new_date_in' and check out date is ‘new_date_out'.

```
$SQL="SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE roomid = '$roomid' AND (( bookings.checkindate < '$new_date_in' AND bookings.checkoutdate >= '$new_date_in') 
           OR (bookings.checkindate < '$new_date_out' AND bookings.checkoutdate > '$new_date_out' )
           OR (bookings.checkindate >= '$new_date_in'  AND bookings.checkoutdate <= '$new_date_out'  )) ;
```

[image]

Bur problem is this retrieve early days which are not in the range.

Ex. If guest select  ‘new_date_in' as 2016/09/25 and ‘new_date_out' as 2016/09/28 of room ID 3

It returns this output

```
534
2016-09-08
2016-09-10
535
2016-08-03
2016-08-05
```

It shouldn’t be returned as output. Please check my SQL query and correct it.

Thank you.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me.  I get zero results with this:

```
CREATE TABLE bookings (
    bookingid int primary key not null,
    checkindate date not null,
    checkoutdate date not null,
    roomid int not null,
    guestid int not null,
    qty int not null
);

insert into bookings (bookingid, checkindate, checkoutdate, roomid, guestid, qty)
values
    (524,'2016-08-01','2016-08-03',2,85,1),
    (525,'2016-10-12','2016-10-15',3,86,1),
    (526,'2016-07-23','2016-07-31',2,87,3),
    (527,'2016-07-26','2016-07-28',1,88,1),
    (533,'2016-07-28','2016-08-02',2,96,1),
    (534,'2016-09-08','2016-09-10',3,97,1),
    (535,'2016-08-03','2016-08-05',3,98,2);

SELECT *
FROM bookings
WHERE roomid = 3
    AND (
           (bookings.checkindate < '2016-09-25' AND bookings.checkoutdate >= '2016-09-25')
        OR (bookings.checkindate < '2016-09-28' AND bookings.checkoutdate > '2016-09-28')
        OR (bookings.checkindate >= '2016-09-25' AND bookings.checkoutdate <= '2016-09-28')
    )
```

Does not appear to be an SQL logic error.  That leaves the following topping the list possible problems:

1. Data type problems.  If you didn't use sane data types for your data fields, you could get unexpected results.  I can't see your table definition.
2. Problem with string concatenation in your application.  There's a reason you're supposed to use parameters.  Take a look at the *actual value* of `$SQL` before it's executed.

Comment: Ok. I''l check. Thankz for your effort.